# Android - using png file instead of a shape in layer-list

Tags: xml, view, android

I would like to use a specific png file as my shape instead of the predefined ones like oval , rectangle ,line etc.   Is this possible.. here is my layer-list xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval"
            >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:dashGap="2dp"
                android:dashWidth="1dp"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/alert_inner_color" />
            <size
                android:height="33dp" android:width="2dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

see how it forces me to use oval.  I have my own png which i want to use to create a divider.  My end goal is to create a divider that can be used to serperate views.   My png file is a single dot. Check this image, the very last column is what i'd like to end up with but have it be only 35dp in height:  [sample image](http://cdn.graphicblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/simplespacers.jpg)

Comment: so instead of shape tag use bitmap tag,  is it what you want?

Comment: close i tried your way but im not quite there. What my end goal is that i have a tiny png file which contains a tiny dot. I want to make a vertical seperator 35dp tall that repeats these dots. So the dots start north and repeat south for a height of 35dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description and your comment back to @pskink, what you want to use is a 9-patch.  See this doc: [9-patch resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) for the XML details.  This is what most of the framework UI layer/state list drawables, etc. use.

UPDATE EDIT: based on the comment discussion, the above 9-patch info won't work.  There's not really a mechanism available which could be used to repeat the same "dot" image over and over, so you'd have to create one.  What you could do is create your own `RepeatingPictureDrawable` class which extends `PictureDrawable` (or event `Drawable`) and override the `draw()` method to draw your repeating dot image.  I would recommend adding custom attributes to specify if the image should be repeated vertically or horizontally.  Using this mechanism, you could have your app only include the single "dot" image and at runtime it scales appropriately.

Comment: can you show me what the code would look like using a 9 patch ?

Comment: You'll need both the revised XML (see the link I provided) as well as updated 9-patch formatted PNG files.  See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for details on the format.

Comment: i dont think this is what i need.  The end result should be like this http://cdn.graphicblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/simplespacers.jpg .I appreicate any further feedback.  Im just looking to take single dot (lets say its a 9 patch) and make it repeat vertically to make a divider.

Comment: A 9 patch will work perfectly for that and is the recommended approach.  Your 9 patch file would be 9x9 pixels with the center pixel the "dot" color you wish and black dots at (0, 1) and (1, 0) x and y coordinates.  Set that as the background resource for a View.  Set the width to 1dp, set the height to "match_parent" or whatever dimension you want and the system will automatically "stretch" your 1 dot PNG image vertically.

Comment: interesting but the issue is i dont necessary want to stretch the dots i want the to REPEAT dots vertically. So the dividider would be dotted like this "........" but vertically. Would this do that ? i imagine it only stretching the single dot across the container.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I missed the "repeating dot" part of this and thought you wanted the dot basically stretched like what a 9-patch will provide.  I'll update my original answer with another route you could take, though it's not going to be a simple, ready-made approach.